# can you restore a single report in SQL Server 2012 ReportServer?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

Basically, I am an intern and there is a report server which we are looking at increasing the power of a certain user on so he can edit more reports than just the ones in his folder.  We know how to do this fine but what I wanted to make sure was that if he messes one up we can easily restore that report.  We are preforming regular backups and I know how to do a full recovery but I cannot find any information about restoring just a single report when needed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options.

1. Edit the report in Visual Studio deploy it to the target server and save the .rdl file in a source repository. You can deploy the saved version as many times as you need to.
2. Log into the reporting services manager and select the report and then select the export option. Save the .rdl file to source repository. You can upload the saved file to the server as many times as you need to.

**Updated**

1. [Here](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2011/03/28/how-to-download-all-your-ssrs-report-definitions-rdl-files-using-powershell/) is a link to a powershell script that seems to create a backup of all .rdl files and saves them to a folder.
2. Search for third party tools that will create and restore one or many individual reports.

Comment: Ok thanks, is there a way to do option 2 for a selection of reports or do I need to do this one report at a time?

Comment: The reporting management application only allows for exporting a single report at a time. I do not remember seeing a backup folder options. There are third party tools that may add this ability. Also, if you make backups of the SSRS database then you can restore from a backup set and you don't have to worry about the individual rdl files.

Comment: yea that backs them all up but I can't find anything saying you can restore just one report instead of all of them sense they are all stored together in BAK files. If there is no way to do this we will just decide what is worth it because we have hundreds of reports and restoring all of them because one got messed up would be not the best solution and going through and making backups of all the reports manually also seems like a bad option.

Comment: I updated the answer with a powershell command script that will pull out the rdl's.